# How to create an IP packet with timestamp field using Scapy

Tags: networking, ip, scapy, icmp

I am new with scapy. I tried creating an IP packet with options field having security set with the following scapy code.

```
packet = IP(dst="10.230.228.146", options=IPOption('\x81\x30'))
```

But every time I try running it, it throws an ICMP reply with type field set to 12, code field set to 0 and pointer field also set to 0.

```
<IP version=4 ihl=5 tos=0x0 len=52 id=16349 flags= frag=0 ttl=128 proto=icmp
chksum=0x7793 src=10.*.*.* dst=10.*.*.* | <ICMP type=parameter-problem
code=ip-header-bad chksum=0xf3ea ptr=0 length=0 unused=None | <IPerror
version=4 ihl=6 tos=0x0 len=24 id=1 flags= frag=0 ttl=64 proto=ip chksum=0x40b
src=10.*.*.* dst=10.*.*.* options=[<IPOption_Security copy_flag=1
optclass=debug option=security length=129 security=12288 |>] |>>>
```

Please help if you know how to correct this.

Thanks

I tried creating an IP packet with options field having security set with the following scapy code.

```
packet = IP(dst="10.230.228.146", options=IPOption('\x81\x30'))
```

I got this ICMP message in response.

```
<IP version=4 ihl=5 tos=0x0 len=52 id=16349 flags= frag=0 ttl=128 proto=icmp
chksum=0x7793 src=10.*.*.* dst=10.*.*.* |<ICMP type=parameter-problem
code=ip-header-bad chksum=0xf3ea ptr=0 length=0 unused=None |<IPerror version=4
ihl=6 tos=0x0 len=24 id=1 flags= frag=0 ttl=64 proto=ip chksum=0x40b
src=10.*.*.* dst=10.*.*.* options=[<IPOption_Security copy_flag=1
optclass=debug option=security length=129 security=12288 |>] |>>>
```

Please help how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where you came up with those options. If you want the option copied to all fragments, then you would set the high-order bit to `1`. Then you have two bits for the Class, and that would be `10` for "*debugging and measurement*." The next five bits are for the Number, which would be `00100` for "*Internet Timestamp*."

After that, you have other values. It is clearly explained in *[RFC 791, Internet Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791)*:

> ```
>   Internet Timestamp
>
>     +--------+--------+--------+--------+
>     |01000100| length | pointer|oflw|flg|
>     +--------+--------+--------+--------+
>     |         internet address          |
>     +--------+--------+--------+--------+
>     |             timestamp             |
>     +--------+--------+--------+--------+
>     |                 .                 |
>                       .
>                       .
>     Type = 68
>
>     The Option Length is the number of octets in the option counting
>     the type, length, pointer, and overflow/flag octets (maximum
>     length 40).
>
>     The Pointer is the number of octets from the beginning of this
>     option to the end of timestamps plus one (i.e., it points to the
>     octet beginning the space for next timestamp).  The smallest
>     legal value is 5.  The timestamp area is full when the pointer
>     is greater than the length.
>
>     The Overflow (oflw) [4 bits] is the number of IP modules that
>     cannot register timestamps due to lack of space.
>
>     The Flag (flg) [4 bits] values are
>
>       0 -- time stamps only, stored in consecutive 32-bit words,
>
>       1 -- each timestamp is preceded with internet address of the
>            registering entity,
>
>       3 -- the internet address fields are prespecified.  An IP
>            module only registers its timestamp if it matches its own
>            address with the next specified internet address.
>
>     The Timestamp is a right-justified, 32-bit timestamp in
>     milliseconds since midnight UT.  If the time is not available in
>     milliseconds or cannot be provided with respect to midnight UT
>     then any time may be inserted as a timestamp provided the high
>     order bit of the timestamp field is set to one to indicate the
>     use of a non-standard value.
>
>     The originating host must compose this option with a large
>     enough timestamp data area to hold all the timestamp information
>     expected.  The size of the option does not change due to adding
>     timestamps.  The intitial contents of the timestamp data area
>     must be zero or internet address/zero pairs.
>
>     If the timestamp data area is already full (the pointer exceeds
>     the length) the datagram is forwarded without inserting the
>     timestamp, but the overflow count is incremented by one.
>
>     If there is some room but not enough room for a full timestamp
>     to be inserted, or the overflow count itself overflows, the
>     original datagram is considered to be in error and is discarded.
>     In either case an ICMP parameter problem message may be sent to
>     the source host [3].
>
>     The timestamp option is not copied upon fragmentation.  It is
>     carried in the first fragment.  Appears at most once in a
>     datagram.
> ```
>
> Padding:  variable
>
> ```
> The internet header padding is used to ensure that the internet
> header ends on a 32 bit boundary.  The padding is zero.
> ```